# Assign string value to Routes

Tags: flutter

I want to show some items as a grid and the grid items should be clickable, but I am having problem of routing. How can I route each item to its unqiue name e.g aa,bb,cc. As you can see in test class i can write `Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.aa);` but what it does is that all items are routed to aa.

Items list:

```
List Fin = [
["aa", "Resources/Images/test/aa.png"],
["bb", "Resources/Images/test/bb.png"],
["cc", "Resources/Images/test/cc.png"],];
```

GridView Code:

```
GridView.builder(
        physics: const ScrollPhysics(),
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: Fin.length,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 10, mainAxisSpacing: 10),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Test(
            title: Fin[index][0],
            icon: Fin[index][1],
          );
        },
      ),
```

Test Class:

```
 return InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.NeedSeparateRouteForEachItem);
  },
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You require two minor changes to be made:

1. In you Test Class:

```dart
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    context.pushNamed(Routes.item,pathParameters: {'item': title});
  },
  child: Container(
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.green,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
  ),
)
```

2. In your GoRouter

```dart
GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: Routes.item.path+':item',
      name: Routes.item.name,
      pageBuilder: (ctx, state) {
        return const MaterialPage(
          child: ItemPage(title: state.pathParameters['item']),
        );
      },
    ),
  ],
)
```

Where definition of `Routes` is

```dart
class Routes{
  static final RouteDetails item = RouteDetails('details','/detail');
}
```

```dart
class RouteDetails {
  RouteDetails(this.name, this.path);
  final String name;
  final String path;
}
```

Comment: This is my current routes.dart file, can't i use this type of method?
` /// Navigator support class to provide link to routes
class Routes {
  Routes._();

  /// Link to main page
  static const String main_page = '/main_page';

  /// Link to converter page
  static const String converter = '/converter';

  /// Links map
  static final Map<String, WidgetBuilder> routes = <String, WidgetBuilder>{
    main_page: (BuildContext context) => MainPage(),
    converter: (BuildContext context) => ConverterWidget(),
  };
} `

Comment: definitely you can the only change required in the addition of `:item` or whatever you what to call it. Just make sure to have the same one in pathParameter map key. Like I kept it to `item`